# Accessing dynamically created arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am dynamically creating arrays in a for loop. This works perfectly but I am not sure how I can access the array from another function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var title = "This is a title";
var paragraph = "Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio.";

w = window;

for (i=0; i<10; i++){

    w["arr_"+i] = [];

    w["arr_"+i].push(title + i);
    w["arr_"+i].push(paragraph);

    console.log(w["arr_"+i]);

}

});

function showArray(){

//I want to use the array data here
// this returns "arr3 is not defined "
console.log(arr3);

}

showArray();
```

Comment: um the array properties you are adding to the window object are arr_, so surely console.log(arr_3) would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

You have underscore in your code.

```
console.log(arr_3);
```

Comment: My fault in pasting the code. console.log(arr_3); still returns undefined. Thanks xdazz